# VBA последовательный запуск макросов в Excel

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Макрос запускает другие макросы последовательно. Макросы работают с Excel таблицами. Нужно запускать макрос, если выполнение предыдущего завершено.

В текущем варианте:

```
Sub ОбновитьБазу()
    Application.Run "Открыть"
    Application.Run "Загрузка"
    Application.Run "Выгрузка"
    Application.Run "Закрыть"
End Sub
```

Некоторые макросы, разумеется, начинают работать раньше, чем завершаются предыдущие.

Из вариантов решения на ум приходят:

- счетчик и его отслеживание
- запуск по времени

Но я уверена, есть какое-то более правильное и красивое решение.

Comment: Что в данном случае "макрос"? подпрограмма на VBA? тогда тупо CALL - он синхронный.

Comment: может попробуете циклы?! Типа: If макрос "Открыть" завершен, Then макрос "Загрузка" начать

Comment: @Akina так тоже не работает, как нужно, первые макросы - убегают вперед. один из макросов работает достаточно долго (скачивает страницы из сети), и еще во время его работы выполняются следующие в последовательности

Comment: Так у вас ещё и внутри макросов что-то асинхронно выполняется? ну тогда не знаю... заводите флаги выполнения и отслеживайте их значения, что ли.

Comment: В *VBA* код выполняется последовательно. Процедура *ОбновитьБазу* передает управление процедуре *Открыть* и ждет завершения ее работы. После отработки *Открыть* управление переходит к процедуре *Загрузка*... и т.д... Возможно. даные на каком-то этапе (*Загрузка* или *Выгрузка*) не успевают обновиться, но это не имеет отношения к последовательности выполнения макросов

Answer (score 1):

*Application.Run* - это не самый простой и широко используемый способ запускать макросы (программы, функции) в VBA. Не углубляясь в детали, для Вашего случая подойдут такие способы:

- имя_программы (макроса) и без скобок перечисление аргументов через
  запятую
- Call имя_программы и в скобках перечисление аргументов через
  запятую.

Ниже - пример тестовой программы с обоими типами синтаксиса. По результатам выполнения видно, что программы выполняются строго последовательно, а не одновременно, как в Вашем случае.

```
Sub TEST()
Dim wait_sec_1 As Integer, wait_sec_2 As Integer
    wait_sec_1 = 10
    wait_sec_2 = 5
    
    Macros1 wait_sec_1
    Macros2 wait_sec_2
    
    Call Macros1(wait_sec_1)
    Call Macros2(wait_sec_2)
    
End Sub


Sub Macros1(wait_sec_1 As Integer)
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To wait_sec_1
        Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")): DoEvents 'one second wait
    Next i
    Debug.Print "First Macros work end"
End Sub

Sub Macros2(wait_sec_2 As Integer)
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To wait_sec_2
        Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")): DoEvents 'one second wait
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Second Macros work end"
End Sub
```

Comment: >> *программы выполняются строго последовательно, а не одновременно, как в Вашем случае* - да не выполняются они там одновременно! Дополните Ваш макрос проверки двумя строками (`Application.Run "Macros1", time1`  и  `Application.Run "Macros2", time2`) и убедитесь. +++ Переменные счетчиков тоже надо объявлять +++ Переменные `time`,тип  `Integer` (целое), это никак не время +++ Единица - не секунда, запись задержки должна быть примерно такой: `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))`, или, если исключить цикл: `Application.Wait (Now + time1 / 86400)` +++  Почему процедура *Private*?

Comment: Спасибо большое vikttur, замечания все по делу. Действительно, я не критично воспринял содержание вопроса в той части, что "Некоторые макросы, разумеется, начинают работать раньше, чем завершаются предыдущие." По остальным замечаниям внесу изменения в ответ как только будет немного свободного времени